# Putting the virus in its place!

Tags: syntax

My schooldays Latin is very rusty! please help with translating 'pneumonia and the virus are losers'
Sunt should go at the end?
Victus should be plural and accusative?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple options:

1. **pneumonia pestisque victae sunt**.

- "Pneumonia and the virus are conquered." Both subjects are Nom. pl. fem.
- I prefer *pestis* over *virus*. *Pestis* is a plague or disease. *Virus* refers only to a poisonous liquid. For example, Lucretius uses *pestis* for the plague of Athens.
- If you insist on using *virus,* change the adjectives from fem. to masc. (*victae* -> *victi*)

2. **pneumonia pestisque fessae sunt**.

- This version means the virus is "exhausted."

3. **pneumonia pestisque perditores sunt**.

- This is the most literal translation, but also the least accurate. It can have the double meaning that the virus is a "destroyer" (lit. "loss-maker") rather than a "loser."

I think you're aware that a colloquialism like "a loser" meaning "a (pathetic) competitor who loses a lot" can't maintain its casual register when translated.

Comment: Thank you. I remember now why I found Latin so difficult!